# How to subtract two cumulative aggregates column in oracle query

Tags: oracle

I have this code:

```sql
SELECT
    SUM(SUM(INCOME))OVER(ORDER BY TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(PAYMENT_DATE, 'MM/YYYY'), 'MM/YYYY'))
        AS CUMULATIVE_INCOME,
    SUM(SUM(EXPENSE))OVER(ORDER BY TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(PAYMENT_DATE, 'MM/YYYY'), 'MM/YYYY'))
        AS CUMULATIVE_EXPENSE,
    SUM(INCOME) AS TOTAL_MONTH_INCOME,
    SUM(EXPENSE) AS TOTAL_MONTH_EXPENSE,
    TO_CHAR(PAYMENT_DATE, 'MM/YYYY') AS MONTH
FROM 
   V_CFW_CASH_FLOW
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(PAYMENT_DATE, 'MM/YYYY')
ORDER BY TO_DATE(MONTH, 'MM/YYYY') ASC
```

What I want is another column which contains the result of subtracting the cumulative income - cumulative expense.

I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```sql
SUM(SUM(INCOME))OVER(ORDER BY TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(PAYMENT_DATE, 'MM/YYYY'), 'MM/YYYY'))
- SUM(SUM(EXPENSE))OVER(ORDER BY TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(PAYMENT_DATE, 'MM/YYYY'), 'MM/YYYY'))
AS NET,
```

Comment: Instead of `OVER ORDER BY TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(PAYMENT_DATE, 'MM/YYYY'), 'MM/YYYY')` , just use `OVER ( ORDER BY PAYMENT_DATE )`  and keep other transformations separately in an outer select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a common table expression:

```
WITH cteSUMS AS (SELECT TO_CHAR(PAYMENT_DATE, 'MM/YYYY') AS MONTH,
                        SUM(SUM(INCOME))
                           OVER (ORDER BY TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(PAYMENT_DATE, 'MM/YYYY'), 'MM/YYYY'))
                           AS CUMULATIVE_INCOME,
                        SUM(SUM(EXPENSE))
                          OVER (ORDER BY TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(PAYMENT_DATE, 'MM/YYYY'), 'MM/YYYY'))
                          AS CUMULATIVE_EXPENSE,
                        SUM(INCOME) AS TOTAL_MONTH_INCOME,
                        SUM(EXPENSE) AS TOTAL_MONTH_EXPENSE
                   FROM V_CFW_CASH_FLOW
                   GROUP BY TO_CHAR(PAYMENT_DATE, 'MM/YYYY'))
SELECT MONTH,
       CUMULATIVE_INCOME,
       CUMULATIVE_EXPENSE,
       TOTAL_MONTH_INCOME,
       TOTAL_MONTH_EXPENSE,
       TOTAL_MONTH_INCOME - TOTAL_MONTH_EXPENSE AS NET
  FROM cteSUMS
  ORDER BY TO_DATE(MONTH, 'MM/YYYY') ASC
```

If you want, you can use two common table expressions to make it even clearer:

```
WITH cteDATA AS (SELECT TO_CHAR(PAYMENT_DATE, 'MM/YYYY') AS MONTH,
                        INCOME,
                        EXPENSE
                   FROM V_CFW_CASH_FLOW),
     cteSUMS AS (SELECT MONTH,
                        SUM(SUM(INCOME))
                           OVER (ORDER BY TO_DATE(MONTH, 'MM/YYYY'))
                           AS CUMULATIVE_INCOME,
                        SUM(SUM(EXPENSE))
                          OVER (ORDER BY TO_DATE(MONTH, 'MM/YYYY'))
                          AS CUMULATIVE_EXPENSE,
                        SUM(INCOME) AS TOTAL_MONTH_INCOME,
                        SUM(EXPENSE) AS TOTAL_MONTH_EXPENSE
                   FROM cteDATA
                   GROUP BY MONTH)
SELECT MONTH,
       CUMULATIVE_INCOME,
       CUMULATIVE_EXPENSE,
       TOTAL_MONTH_INCOME,
       TOTAL_MONTH_EXPENSE,
       TOTAL_MONTH_INCOME - TOTAL_MONTH_EXPENSE AS NET
  FROM cteSUMS
  ORDER BY TO_DATE(MONTH, 'MM/YYYY') ASC
```

Best of luck.